# How to detect and handle very different screen sizes in WinRT-Apps?

Tags: gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro, screen-resolution

I am wondering what the best way is to detect (and handle) very different screen sizes.

Why I ask that: I have a metro (Win8 UI)-styled app with a GridView (and different items), see mockup. For every category I chose several which I show on the first page. If the screen size (resolution) is small (e.g. on a tablet), I only want to show 3-4 items per category. On a large screen I could probably show 10 items. Otherwise there will be very much unused, empty space. (On the detailpage this is no problem, because I show all items and it automatically adjusts to the bigger screen size.)

This is also the intention of Steven Sinofsky (Microsoft) as he has written in his [BlogPost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/03/21/scaling-to-different-screens.aspx).

This is the mockup of my app on a small screen.

[image: Win8 RT app mockup on small screen]

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just inspect the values of `this.Frame.ActualWidth` and `this.Frame.ActualHeight` in your page when it is loaded to work out roughly how many items you want to show.  Be aware of scaling, though - this might make your calculations a little more complex, but not overly so.  Since you should probably know the sizes of the elements in the grid view, you should be able to work out how many would fit sensibly in the screen area you have.  Then it is just a case of Take-ing the appropriate number of items into your viewmodel and then binding it the the view.